# Explicit wait not getting applied

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write following code but I am getting `NoSuchElementException`. I see that the explicit wait is not getting applied.

```
WebDriver driver = WebDriverManager.chromedriver().create();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("abc");
driver.findElement(By.id("-signin-username")).sendKeys("pratik.p@feg.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("-signin-password")).sendKeys("abcdf");
driver.findElement(By.id("-signin-submit")).click();
// wait(100);
waitForElementToLoad(driver, driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("portal-application[title='AW Acc']")), 100);
```

Below is the 'Explicit Wait' method.

```
public static void waitForElementToLoad(WebDriver driver, WebElement element,int seconds) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}
```

Using forced wait `Thread.sleep()` the code works but I don't want any forced wait in the code as it slows down the execution. Can anyone help? I am getting this in the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"portal-application[title='AW Acc']"}
  (Session info: chrome=102.0.5005.115)
```

Comment: share the url to the website you're trying to automate?

Comment: Actually its AWS site. I cannot share with you the URL and Credentials.

Comment: Error says that `driver` cannot find element by css selector `portal-application[title='AW Acc']`. So `waitForElementToLoad` method works fine, but the locator itself is invalid, you need to change it.

Comment: The locator is right. When I apply Thread.sleep(), it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
...
driver.findElement(By.id("-signin-submit")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("portal-application[title='AW Acc']")));
```

You catch exception because webdriver tries to find element **before** checking it's visibility. So what it does is:

1. Find element by css selector `portal-application[title='AW Acc']`
2. Wait for element to be visible (it's height and width more than 0)

and it fails on step 1 because element is not in the DOM yet.

**If it doesn't work, then try Fluent Waits:**

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
        .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

WebElement element = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("portal-application[title='AW Acc']"));
    }
});
```

**Also**, just in case you decide you want it, there is a dirty way that works in any case:

```
public static WebElement findMyElement(WebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutSeconds) throws Exception {

    long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + (timeoutSeconds * 1000);
    while (true) {
        try {
            return driver.findElement(by);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException nEx) {
            Thread.sleep(50);
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() > timeout) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Still can't find the element..");
            }
        }
    }
}
...
WebElement element = findMyElement(driver, By.cssSelector("portal-application[title='AW Acc']"), 20);
```